# Serialize/store a TinyMCE bookmark across page loads

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a situation where I need to save the contents of the TinyMCE editor to a database, then retrieve them later with the caret/cursor position restored.

I see in the [TinyMCE documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.getBookmark) that it *might* be possible using `getBookmark()`, for example:

`var bm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();`

However, I cannot work out how to serialize the value returned by `getBookmark()`
If I save it to a text box like this:

`$('#myTextBoxId').val(bm);`

the value just shows as `[Object] [Object]`.

Is it even possible to save the bookmark across page postbacks?

Comment: You are seeing `[Object]` because the bookmark is an object.  You can encode it to a string using JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoseM's comment, the answer is uber-simple:

```
var bm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();
$('#myTextBoxId').val(JSON.stringify(bm));
```